# WPF UserControl that does not derive from UserControl directly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I Would like to create several WPF `UserControl` classes with some common functionality. For this reason I would like to derive the classes from a new base class that in turns derives from `UserControl`.

My problem is that my C# class is defined `partial`, and the automatically generated other part `derives` from `UserControl` and *not* from my new base class. Can I make Visual Studio derive the partial class from my base class instead of `UserControl`?

Comment: When you say _the automatically generated other part_, do you mean the .xaml file?

Comment: No I meant the hidden cs file named xyz.g.i.cs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure - create a class that serves as the base call for your user controls:

```
public class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    //TODO: Add your common functionality
}
```

Next, create a user control, and change the root declaration to reference your base class:

```
<controls:BaseUserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</controls:BaseUserControl>
```

And change the partial class to match as well:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : BaseUserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I did this in my project when it was 4.0. Now, if I do the exact same code in 4.5, I lose the preview and I get a compile-time error: The name "BaseUserControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication2".

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez I just updated my repro to 4.5 and had no problems compiling or in design time preview.  You might want to ask a new question...

Comment: I forgot to mention one important thing: This happens in VS2012. Unfortunately, I don't have VS2010 right now to re-test this behaviour

Comment: Just a quick update: I've just installed VS2010 and the exact same code above works in VS2010, but not in VS2012